# Are there reasons for an app developer not to sign all of their apps with the same signature?

Tags: android, android-signing

According to the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#considerations), apps that are signed with the same signature have special capabilities like running on the same process (if needed) and using signature-level permission protection level.

Cons for signing several apks with the same signature are the inability to sell one APK without giving away your signature, and the risk of having lost signature credentials affect all of the signed apps.

Say these cons do not bother me. Are there any other cons I should be aware of for signing several APKs with the same signature?

Comment: Well, F-Droid signs all Applications using the same Keys. Guessing they must be very confident in having just ine keypair.

Comment: Yea, I saw several references for companies that use the same certificate for several apps. The thing is - this is barely documented, and so I'm asking to see if people encountered issues